# Is there a way to have a component on multiple page without using bootstrap in the root module?

Tags: angular

I'm kind of stuck and I don't know how to implement this.
I have a sidebar that appear on multiple page that are kind of linked, it's a sort of progress bar where you can see what you have selected before and navigate between them.

The thing is this sidebar don't appear on all page but only on those specific 4 pages. I didn't find anything that could match what I want. The solution that seems good would be something like bootstrap on the root module but it seems like it can only be used once on the root module.

Do you guys any other way to do what this ?

Thank's for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I was taking the wrong approach. I just needed the include a rooter-outlet to my route component and add what change into my child component.

My route look like this :

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: ChoicePageComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'field',
      component: FieldChoiceScene
    },
    {
      path: 'subfield',
      component: SubfieldChoiceScene
    }
  ]
}];
```

And my ChoicePageComponent :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'choice-page',
  template: `
  <choice-sidebar></choice-sidebar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./choice-page.scss']
})
export class ChoicePageComponent { }
```

With this, it load FieldChoiceScene or SubfieldChoiceScene component depending on my route.